# RDLC LocalReport performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rdlc

I am using the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` to generate an excel file from a list of objects inside a WPF application. When running the export from the WPF application, it takes a very long time (more than 15 minutes). However, with the same data sets run inside a unit test, the export operation takes around 30 seconds.

Has anybody else encountered this behavior?

Comment: did you find  a solution?

Comment: Actually, I didn't. I resolved to using EPplus or similar libraries since no complicated formatting was required